# Ошибка в композере

Tags: composer

В композере ошибка

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1761083392) (tried to allocate 268435456 bytes) in phar://W:/modules/php/PHP-5.6/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 126
```

в настройках php:

```
memory_limit = -1
```

как избежать ошибки? заранее спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте поставить любое другое значение кроме -1, скорее всего все заработает.

Comment: @Евгений Иванов это Вы знаете, или предполагаете? Дело в то что ошибка связанна с превышением лимита памяти. Изначально было 1500М. Я на форумах почитал, чтобы дать композеру полный полет действия нужно установить значение -1. Т е я ставил и 3000М и тоже была ошибка. А теперь напишите конкретнее о величине, которую мне нужно поставить.

Comment: Это предположения, и как проверку я думал вам следовалобы поставить иное от -1 значение.

Comment: Я же вам говорю что пробовал 1500 и 3000(эффект тот же, количество памяти в ошибке меняется только), какие ещё будут предложения?